# How to intercept upload requests when using ng6-file-man?

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am creating file upload functionality for my application using the example [ng6-file-man-test](https://github.com/Chiff/ng6-file-man-test) which uses [ng6-file-man](https://github.com/AnnotationSro/ng6-file-man) module to enable varies file/folder manipulation functionalities. According to my application requirements I am also using an interceptor for the requests to add a token to them. The interceptor works fine for most of the requests but not for the upload and download request.

> jwt.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpResponse }
  from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


    const duplicate = request.clone({ params: request.params.set('token', 'jwt-token') });

    return next.handle(duplicate);
  }
}
```

I haven't made any changes to the AppComponent which is given in the example.

> The following is the app.module.ts with the interceptor added.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FileManagerModule } from 'ng6-file-man';
import { JwtInterceptor } from '../_helpers/jwt.interceptor';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FileManagerModule

  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: JwtInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

File Manager component is as follows

```
    export class FileManagerComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked {
  tree: TreeModel;
  appLanguage = 'it';

  constructor() {
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    const treeConfig: ConfigInterface = {
      baseURL: 'https://backend.com/',
      api: {
        listFile: 'api/file/list',
        uploadFile: 'api/file/upload?token=' + currentUser.access_token,
        downloadFile: 'api/file/download',
        deleteFile: 'api/file/remove',
        createFolder: 'api/file/directory',
        renameFile: 'api/file/rename',
        searchFiles: 'api/file/search'
      },
      options: {
        allowFolderDownload: false,
        showFilesInsideTree: true
      }
    };

    this.tree = new TreeModel(treeConfig);
  }

  itemClicked(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    console.log('after');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('before');

    let container = document.querySelector('.file-manager-left');

  }

}
```

I would like to know if there is a possible way in which I can intercept the `upload` and `download` requests which are made to the backend by the module.

Answer (score 0):

It should be caused because for all requests that you are intercepting you expect usage of `HttpService`.

- Uplodad is using FineUploader library which seems not to be connected with `HttpService`
- Download is made by opening new window with inserted parameters containing only `path.id`

---

We would be happy if you propose any solution on our [GitHub issues](https://github.com/AnnotationSro/ng6-file-man/issues)